# IPv6 on ESXi with Hetzner

Tags: debian, vmware-esxi, ipv6, hetzner

I'm having trouble with this one since I'm neither good at ESXi or networking so I'm mostly just following tutorials without being very sure about what I'm doing.

So I just followed [this guide](https://community.hetzner.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-routervm-for-vmware-vsphere) to use a separate VM as a router. Everything went fine up until the last step, since the "test" VM has no connection (the router one does).

This tutorial is supposed to work for an IPv6 subnet, as stated in the conclusion

> By following these steps, servers with VMware vSphere will be able to use IPs from both IPv4 and IPv6 subnets.

But I'm just unable to install the "test" debian VM with an IPv6 (I don't have any more IPv4 other than the one for the router, just a /64 IPv6 subnet).

So, suppose I've done all the previous steps well (A big assumption, but I did not stray from the guide), then I'm at the Debian installation, the steps I'm following are:

1. Autoconfiguration and DHCP fail as expected. I choose manual configuration
2. As an IP address I enter an IPv6 IP unused in the router machine (e.g. `2001:db8:1234::4`)
3. As a netmask I use `ffff:fff:fff:ffff::`
4. As a gateway I use the one commented with `# IPv6 address for bridged interface` (In the tutorial, it specifies another IPv6 as a gateway that hasn't appeared anywhere until now, is this a mistake?), also, I tried with the IPv6 commented as `# one IPv6 address of IPv6 prefix`, but no luck
5. I enter the three nameservers given in the last example
6. The installation only fails when choosing a mirror

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: normaly you use a subnet mask like /64 for ipv6, if you really enter the mask as you did, make sure it is 4 f in each part, if not fill out with 0 at the _end_. If you have one external /64 then you dont have enough to run your own firewall, try to get a 56 and make sure that you can get delegation on subnets.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Are you sure about that? If I enter `ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::` the process fails inmediately telling me that the gateway is un reachable. I've read somewhere that I *may* need an additional NIC so maybe that's what's missing? I'm really grasping at straws here because I don't know in which cases I'd need it and for what reasons

Comment: I'm so dumb! turns out I just had to use the router VM link-local IP as a gateway, obviously, just like for IPv4. Now I have other problems related to DNS but at least I have a connection